# Electronics not working after trying to replace stereo

Tags: electrical

The trunk release, power locks, key fob, radio, interior lights, power mirrors, and the horn (horn only works when car is running) all don't work but my power windows still work great. What could be the problem? I checked my fuses and they seem fine.

Comment: What is the make/year/model of the car?

Comment: 2002 Chrysler Sebring

Comment: "after trying to replace stereo" - Who did that? Are you sure no plugs are left unplugged (maybe missed some?). Also what components were changed exactly? If you did that yourself you may have missed few wires or maybe you damaged some?

Answer (score 1):

Given that your fuses are fine, the logical explanation would be a break in the wiring that is common to all the affected components.

The fact that the power windows indicate that they are on a different electrical circuit.

The obvious thing to check is the area around the stereo since that is where the wiring was disturbed the most.

Answer (score 0):

Dodge loves running lots of circuits through the radio (this is not uncommon). If you missed one of the plugs on the back of the radio or damaged one or more of the wires that could definitely cause your problem.